# Is it possible to expose custom table data to Views without custom code?

Tags: 8, views

I have a custom table that I'd like to expose to administrators so that they can perform simple searches on the table data. I know I can create a series of custom views handlers for each field, but is there is a way to expose and search through the custom table data without custom coding? I expect there is a contrib module out there that solves this problem, but my Googling has come up dry.

Comment: If you defined it with the Data module, I think you should be able to do just that. However, nothing will be as close as wiring it with the Views API I believe. https://www.drupal.org/project/data

Comment: I did not define this particular table with the Data module.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because questions explicitly asking to recommend, find or compare a module, theme, distribution, or other off-site resource are off-topic for Drupal Answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently [Views Custom Table](https://www.drupal.org/project/view_custom_table) does that:

> View custom table module provide you functionality to integrate your
> custom table data to views, and access all it's column in views. This
> module use hook_view_data to add custom tables in views. this module
> provides you following functionalities.
>
> 1. Auto integrate custom table data to views
> 2. Auto map mysql data types with drual data types
> 3. Extend relationship of custom table data to drupal entities